# Como obtener el valor de un input radio en varios grupos

Tags: javascript

Me explico, quiero obtener el valor de los input radio con un click y este valor se almacenara en un input text, con uno no he tenido problema, pero con 2 o 3 NO me llega a ejecutar.

Aquí ya he hecho uno, pero el punto es que estoy repitiendo código, ¿no habría una manera de simplificarlo? Ya que son 137.

**HTML**

```
<div class="contenedor">

 <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="fruta" class="radio_fruta" value="Manzana">Manzana<label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="fruta" class="radio_fruta" value="Pera">Pera<label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="fruta" class="radio_fruta" value="Platano">Platano<label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="fruta" class="radio_fruta" value="Piña">Piña<label>

    <input type="text" class="campo_fruta" value="Vacio">
 </div>

    <br>
    <br>

    <!--/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->

 <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="numero" class="radio_numero" value="1">1<label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="numero" class="radio_numero" value="2">2<label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="numero" class="radio_numero" value="3">3<label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="numero" class="radio_numero" value="4">4<label>

    <input type="text" class="campo_numero" value="Vacio">
 </div>   

    <br>
    <br>

    <!--/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////-->

 <div>
    <label><input type="radio" name="mascota" class="radio_mascota" value="Perro">Perro<label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="mascota" class="radio_mascota" value="Gato">Gato<label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="mascota" class="radio_mascota" value="Perico">Perico<label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="mascota" class="radio_mascota" value="Tortuga">Tortuga<label>

    <input type="text" class="campo_mascota" value="Vacio">
 </div>   

    <br>
    <br>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
    let radio_fruta = document.querySelectorAll(".radio_fruta")
    let campo_fruta = document.querySelector(".campo_fruta")

    for(let i = 0; i < radio_fruta.length; i++){
    radio_fruta[i].addEventListener("click",function(){

    campo_fruta.value = radio_fruta[i].value

      })
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------

    let radio_numero = document.querySelectorAll(".radio_numero")
    let campo_numero = document.querySelector(".campo_numero")

    for(let i = 0; i < radio_numero.length; i++){
    radio_numero[i].addEventListener("click",function(){

    campo_numero.value = radio_numero[i].value

      })
    }

    //------------------------------------------------------------

    let radio_mascota = document.querySelectorAll(".radio_mascota")
    let campo_mascota = document.querySelector(".campo_mascota")

    for(let i = 0; i < radio_mascota.length; i++){
    radio_mascota[i].addEventListener("click",function(){

    campo_mascota.value = radio_mascota[i].value

      })
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el error que tienes es que no es la misma posicion del radio que la del input text, asi que no puedes usar la variable **i** para los dos.

Entonces para obtener la posicion del input text podrias dividir la posicion actual del radio entre el numero de radios que tiene cada grupo.

```js
let radio = document.querySelectorAll(".radio")
let campo_checkButton = document.querySelectorAll(".campo_checkButton")

for (let i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
   radio[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

      // Obtener posicion del input
      numInputText = Math.floor(i / 4);

      campo_checkButton[numInputText].value = radio[i].value
   })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que puedo ver, el `TypeError` se está originando debido a que tu variable `i` en el `for` puede llegar a ser 12, y tan sólo tienes 3 inputs...

Cuando viene la asignación `campo_checkButton[i].value = radio[i].value` y el valor de i es 3, es cuando tira el error, una manera de comprobar esto es agregar la línea de código

`console.log('Añadiendo listener a input: ', i);`

De tal manera que verás los mensajes de 0 al 2 y en el 3 saldrá el error

Answer (score 0):

Nunca creí que iba a funcionar, pero funciono.

```
let radio_fruta = document.querySelectorAll(".radio_fruta")
    let campo_fruta = document.querySelectorAll(".campo_fruta")

    for(let i = 0; i < radio_fruta.length; i++){
    radio_fruta[i].addEventListener("click",function(){

        for(let y = 0; y < campo_fruta.length; y++){
            campo_fruta[y].value = radio_fruta[i].value
            break;
        }

      })
    }
```

Agregue un for y le añadí un break para que asi pueda identificar al input hasta el orden correcto. GRACIAS A LOS QUE ME DIJERON CUAL ES EL ERROR.